# Why does VS2019 build my assembly in two places?

Tags: visual-studio

I've got a VS2019 solution with 11 C# projects.  One of my assemblies exhibits an odd behavior I cannot seem to fix.

The solution directory structure looks roughly like this (Here I'm only showing two of the assemblies, "MyApp.Core". and "MyApp.Net"

```
MySolution
   |--x64
   |   |---Release  (output binaries for all assemblies for release builds)
   |   |---Debug    (output binaries for all assemblies for debug builds)
   |
   |--MyCompany
         |-- MyApp.Core
         |-- MyApp.Net
         |-- (A bunch of other similar assemblies)
```

All assemblies are targeted to build in one of the two output folders via the Project `Properties >> Build >> Output Path` setting.  It is set to `..\..\x64\Release\` (or `..\..\x64\Debug\`) for all assemblies.   And this all works great.  When I build the solution, all of the output binaries of all of the assemblies go to one of the two output folders under "x64"

Except for one weird thing:

Every single time I even ***open*** the solution, Visual Studio 2019 creates the following subdirectory structure underneath the "MyApp.Net" assembly folder

```
  |--obj
      |--x64
          |--Release
```

If I build Release, I end up with a copy of "MyApp.Net.dll" in ***two*** places:  One in the desired output directory and one here, in this undesired subfolder of MyApp.Net.

- None of my other projects exhibit this behavior
- The Debug build of MyApp.Net does not exhibit this behavior
- If I compare project settings of MyApp.Net to ***any*** others in the solution, item-by-item, they appear to be identical, including the build-output section.
- All projects have only two configurations:  Release and Debug.

Now I know I must be missing something here.  Some Visual Studio setting, some project setting, maybe?  Can give me an idea of why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You only override the output folders, but not the intermediate folders, such as `obj`, so those folders are still generated to hold intermediate output. No matter how "undesired" you feel, those folders are critical to the whole compilation process.

Comment: OK great:  Where may I override the intermediate folders in the settings of a C# project?  None of my other C# projects end up with the "obj" folder so why is it not critical for them?

Comment: Diagnostic logging of MSBuild will reveal all details to you, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2019 So you can then easily override whatever folders you want once you learn the name of them. It will also tell you why other projects did not suffer the same.